# Boot options not shown after BIOS setup update driver installation

Tags: boot, boot-repair

My laptop has two operating systems. One is Windows 10  and the other is Ubuntu.
I installed BIOS setup driver on windows as I was asked to, by one of the customer care executives in the process of solving my cooling fan problem.
After this update, I was asked to restart the system and after this, my boot options got disappeared and when I  start the laptop, windows is getting loaded automatically.
I use Windows very rarely and Ubuntu very often. All my files are there in Ubuntu.
Kindly, help me in getting back ubuntu in boot options. 
Hoping for a fast reply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIOS is actually UEFI.

Just open the settings again and, in the boot menu, where currently is "Windows boot manager", select and change to "Ubuntu" again.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and I accessed my ubuntu but I want boot options to be shown during start up rather than going to advanced restart options and then selecting boot order. Could you just let me how can change the boot order.Now windows is at the top, I want ubuntu to be at the top so that I can access both.

Comment: In Windows disable the Fast Startup feature. Then boot Ubuntu, open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: My problem is solved , in system configuration under boot options, I changed the boot order, previously windows was at top now I changed it and put ubuntu at top so now I can open both ubuntu and windows

Comment: As I told you :) If my answer was useful then please accept it.